# Android format TextView with multiple styles

Tags: android

I have a dictionary database for an offline dictionary and I need to format the definitions.
The dictionary is in Romanian so you won't understand too much from the definition but I will try to explain the format briefly.

definition example: @ABAGERÍE^2@ #s. f.# Meseria de abagiu. - @Abager@ + #suf.# $-ie.$

From the online version, I could discover some things

@ = italic
^ = upperscript
"#" = bold
$ = underline

Is there any way how can I make this possible in android?

Comment: are you parsing the text by yourself? If so you could use a Spannable string and replace the special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the spannable style classes:

```
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello World 123456");

sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 7, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 7, 14, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(), 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
sb.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, 4, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
sb.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 1, 3, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textView.setText(sb);
```

Follow the link to get the full list of [ParcelableSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ParcelableSpan) subclasses:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ParcelableSpan

Comment: Can a bolt and italic be used on the same characters?

Comment: Yes, you can overlap all the spans. the setSpan method takes an start/end character indexes for the span, which can be the same between all the defined spannable.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link to the full list of Spannable classes, so you can find them easily.